# How to communicate from the Request Handler to a Socket Server

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following two Python classes:

```
import socketserver

class MyServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address):
        socketserver.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, MyTcpHandler)
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        self.serve_forever()

class MyTcpHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    data = ""

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(BUFF_SIZE).strip()
        if self.data == b"shutdown":
            self.request.close()
            import threading
            threading.Thread(target=SERVER.shutdown).start()
```

Thus, when the client sends "shutdown", the server itself should shutdown. As a workaround I set the global variable `SERVER` to the `MyServer` object, then I call `SERVER.shutdown` in another thread, as shown above.

But using a global variable is ugly as hell. So how can I communicate directly from the request handler with the socket server instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is available as `self.server` according to the Python docs here https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.handle